# Can't see what's causing this Java syntax error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax

I'm making a Java class in Eclipse Indigo for an Android project.  (I'll be fleshing this class out with some 2D graphics eventually).
I'm getting...

> Syntax error, insert “;” to complete Statement

on the setBitmap call near the end - the compiler is putting the red line showing the error under the closing paren after 'bitmap'.   This is the **entire file** . . .

```
package com.ag.testlayout;

import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.Window;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.View;


public class MyGraphicsView extends View {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public MyGraphicsView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int curw, int curh, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
           bitmap.recycle();
        }
        canvas= new Canvas();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(curw, curh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

I looked for mismatched braces and parens and couldn't see any, but I hope the problem is obvious to someone here.

**EDIT:**  Someone asked what happens if I delete that line.   If I delete that line it moves the same error message up to the closing paren on the previous line, i.e., "_8888); "

Comment: Have you tried to clean/build? I'm not getting the error when I paste code into my IDE.

Comment: I agree with BlackHatSamurei; sometimes clean build helps. The other thing: have you tried to comment out the whole method, class, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend once told me of a prank where someone put a character that was either empty or looked like a semi-colon at the end of statement in order to mess with someone.  If you delete the last line does it compile?  If so, can you try retyping it out?  You could have something silly like a non-displaying character there.

I took a look at your raw pasted code in your post.  You have four stray characters after the last line where you see the error.  Of ascii character 160.  Try to delete all the whitespace after the second to last line the end `}`, including the `}` then retype the `}` to make sure you get it.  If the code was from a copy and paste that should be the issue.

This is an ascii map of whats in your raw post.  If you look near the end of the pasted code you can see what I mean.

```
    13  0D  15
10  0A  12
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
a   97  61  141
c   99  63  143
k   107 6B  153
a   97  61  141
g   103 67  147
e   101 65  145
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
o   111 6F  157
m   109 6D  155
.   46  2E  56
a   97  61  141
g   103 67  147
.   46  2E  56
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
s   115 73  163
t   116 74  164
l   108 6C  154
a   97  61  141
y   121 79  171
o   111 6F  157
u   117 75  165
t   116 74  164
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
v   118 76  166
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
.   46  2E  56
W   87  57  127
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
o   111 6F  157
w   119 77  167
M   77  4D  115
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
a   97  61  141
g   103 67  147
e   101 65  145
r   114 72  162
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
v   118 76  166
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
.   46  2E  56
W   87  57  127
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
o   111 6F  157
w   119 77  167
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
p   112 70  160
.   46  2E  56
A   65  41  101
c   99  63  143
t   116 74  164
i   105 69  151
v   118 76  166
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
y   121 79  171
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
c   99  63  143
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
.   46  2E  56
C   67  43  103
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
x   120 78  170
t   116 74  164
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
c   99  63  143
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
.   46  2E  56
r   114 72  162
e   101 65  145
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
C   67  43  103
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
f   102 66  146
i   105 69  151
g   103 67  147
u   117 75  165
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
t   116 74  164
i   105 69  151
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
g   103 67  147
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
g   103 67  147
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
C   67  43  103
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
g   103 67  147
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
P   80  50  120
a   97  61  141
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
g   103 67  147
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
P   80  50  120
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
m   109 6D  155
p   112 70  160
o   111 6F  157
r   114 72  162
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
.   46  2E  56
v   118 76  166
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
.   46  2E  56
V   86  56  126
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
u   117 75  165
b   98  62  142
l   108 6C  154
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
l   108 6C  154
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
s   115 73  163
32  20  40
M   77  4D  115
y   121 79  171
G   71  47  107
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
V   86  56  126
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
32  20  40
e   101 65  145
x   120 78  170
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
n   110 6E  156
d   100 64  144
s   115 73  163
32  20  40
V   86  56  126
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
32  20  40
{   123 7B  173
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
r   114 72  162
i   105 69  151
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
32  20  40
C   67  43  103
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
r   114 72  162
i   105 69  151
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
32  20  40
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
32  20  40
b   98  62  142
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
u   117 75  165
b   98  62  142
l   108 6C  154
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
32  20  40
M   77  4D  115
y   121 79  171
G   71  47  107
r   114 72  162
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
h   104 68  150
i   105 69  151
c   99  63  143
s   115 73  163
V   86  56  126
i   105 69  151
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
(   40  28  50
C   67  43  103
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
x   120 78  170
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
x   120 78  170
t   116 74  164
)   41  29  51
32  20  40
{   123 7B  173
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
s   115 73  163
u   117 75  165
p   112 70  160
e   101 65  145
r   114 72  162
(   40  28  50
c   99  63  143
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
x   120 78  170
t   116 74  164
)   41  29  51
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
}   125 7D  175
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
@   64  40  100
O   79  4F  117
v   118 76  166
e   101 65  145
r   114 72  162
r   114 72  162
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
e   101 65  145
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
p   112 70  160
r   114 72  162
o   111 6F  157
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
c   99  63  143
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
d   100 64  144
32  20  40
v   118 76  166
o   111 6F  157
i   105 69  151
d   100 64  144
32  20  40
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
S   83  53  123
i   105 69  151
z   122 7A  172
e   101 65  145
C   67  43  103
h   104 68  150
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
g   103 67  147
e   101 65  145
d   100 64  144
(   40  28  50
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
u   117 75  165
r   114 72  162
w   119 77  167
,   44  2C  54
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
u   117 75  165
r   114 72  162
h   104 68  150
,   44  2C  54
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
o   111 6F  157
l   108 6C  154
d   100 64  144
w   119 77  167
,   44  2C  54
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
n   110 6E  156
t   116 74  164
32  20  40
o   111 6F  157
l   108 6C  154
d   100 64  144
h   104 68  150
)   41  29  51
32  20  40
{   123 7B  173
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
i   105 69  151
f   102 66  146
32  20  40
(   40  28  50
b   98  62  142
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
32  20  40
!   33  21  41
=   61  3D  75
32  20  40
n   110 6E  156
u   117 75  165
l   108 6C  154
l   108 6C  154
)   41  29  51
32  20  40
{   123 7B  173
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
b   98  62  142
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
.   46  2E  56
r   114 72  162
e   101 65  145
c   99  63  143
y   121 79  171
c   99  63  143
l   108 6C  154
e   101 65  145
(   40  28  50
)   41  29  51
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
}   125 7D  175
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
=   61  3D  75
32  20  40
n   110 6E  156
e   101 65  145
w   119 77  167
32  20  40
C   67  43  103
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
(   40  28  50
)   41  29  51
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
b   98  62  142
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
32  20  40
=   61  3D  75
32  20  40
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
.   46  2E  56
c   99  63  143
r   114 72  162
e   101 65  145
a   97  61  141
t   116 74  164
e   101 65  145
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
(   40  28  50
c   99  63  143
u   117 75  165
r   114 72  162
w   119 77  167
,   44  2C  54
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
u   117 75  165
r   114 72  162
h   104 68  150
,   44  2C  54
32  20  40
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
.   46  2E  56
C   67  43  103
o   111 6F  157
n   110 6E  156
f   102 66  146
i   105 69  151
g   103 67  147
.   46  2E  56
A   65  41  101
R   82  52  122
G   71  47  107
B   66  42  102
_   95  5F  137
8   56  38  70
8   56  38  70
8   56  38  70
8   56  38  70
)   41  29  51
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
c   99  63  143
a   97  61  141
n   110 6E  156
v   118 76  166
a   97  61  141
s   115 73  163
.   46  2E  56
s   115 73  163
e   101 65  145
t   116 74  164
B   66  42  102
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
(   40  28  50
b   98  62  142
i   105 69  151
t   116 74  164
m   109 6D  155
a   97  61  141
p   112 70  160
)   41  29  51
;   59  3B  73
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
    160 A0  240 <--- Thats not an english character
    160 A0  240
    160 A0  240
    160 A0  240
}   125 7D  175
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
32  20  40
}   125 7D  175
13  0D  15
10  0A  12
```

Comment: Does it compile without that line?

Comment: @ Carlos Bribiescas  if I comment-out that line it moves the error up to the closing paren on the previous line..."_8888);"

Comment: That tells me the error is likely after that line then.

Comment: I found some non-printable characters embedded in the white space in front of the closing curly-brace for the onSizeChanged method.  Those must be the same ones you noticed.  I took those away and the problem vanished.    So thank you!   (Don't compilers or source-code editors know what's printable/displayable and what's not?   Is there some way for the compiler to flag such characters?)

Answer (score 3):

I find that with issues like this, a simple `clean > build` will solve the issue.

Comment: All of my builds are clean > builds

Comment: @user316117 I'm saying rather than expecting the build to clean itself, go into `clean` and then do `build`. If you have an error, you won't be able to build, therefore, it won't clean.

Comment: The Clean option in Eclipse (Project>Clean) automatically initiates a build.  It says "Clean will discard all build problems and states.  The projects will be rebuilt from scratch."  That's how I do all my builds

Comment: @user316117 I'm not able to reproduce. I copied the code from your OP and put it into my own IDE, and it all comes up fine. If cleaning doesn't fix it, you might try restarting your project since you don't have much done already.

Comment: @user316117 You might also try restarting Eclipse.